# Ajax and Jquery trying to get form to submit without refreshing page or url update (SHOPIFY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

Ajax and Jquery trying to get form to submit without refreshing page or URL update (SHOPIFY)
Let me know if anyone has had same issue, looking for a solution :) Anything helps.

No matter what I do it causes a refresh and URL goes to quiz-page?customer_posted=true and refreshes the page.

website page in question is https://ca.viasox.com/pages/quiz-page after the questions have been answered.

HTML

```
<form method="post"  action="/contact"  id="contact_form_quiz-compression" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="newsletter-form-quiz">
                 <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="customer">
                 <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
              <input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="Compression">
              <div class="newsletter-form__field-wrapper">
                <div class="field">
                  <input
                    id="NewsletterForm-Quiz--{{ section.id }}"
                    type="email"
                    name="contact[email]"
                    class="field__input-Quiz"
                    value="{{ form.email }}"
                    aria-required="true"
                    autocorrect="off"
                    autocapitalize="off"
                    autocomplete="email"
                    placeholder="{{ 'newsletter.label' | t }}"
                    required
                  > </input>
                  
                       <div class="quiz-result"><span>
                  <input type="submit" class="newsletter-form__button-quiz field__button-quiz button"  name="commit-quiz" id="Subscribe-quiz2" aria-label="{{ 'newsletter.button_label' | t }}" value="View Results" >
                    
                  </input></span> </div>
                  
                </div>
               </div>
         </form>
```

AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var form2 = $('#contact_form_quiz-compression'),
    // Success function
   
    
   $("#contact_form_quiz-compression").submit(function(e){
    
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form2.attr('action'),
          cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
             success: function(data){
                        alert("Thank's For Submitting Your Email");
                    },
        })
      
        
    });
    
});
```

Comment: In the AJAX section, remove this line:  var form2 = $('#contact_form_quiz-compression'), and change this line url: form2.attr('action'), to this: url: $(this).attr('action'),